# Simple ThinkScript Strategy to Pine Script - No Trades Placed

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

I'm converting a simple ThinkScript strategy to Pine Script. In ThinkScript, it opens many trades over the past few days (5-minute chart on SPY ticker), but when translated to Pine Script, there are no trades placed. Wondering if someone can spot the bug. Note, it uses `request.security` to get data from a higher timeframe/aggregation, not sure if that's the issue or not.

This is the ThinkScript:

```
input agg = AggregationPeriod.HOUR; 
input TrendPeriods = 5;
input use_trading_hours = yes;
input spread = 0.15;

######################################################
# TIME
######################################################
def startTradingTime = if use_trading_hours == yes then 0930 else 0000;
def noMorePositions = if use_trading_hours == yes then 1530 else 0000;
def endTradingTime = if use_trading_hours == yes then 1600 else 0000;
def isTradingSession = if use_trading_hours == yes then SecondsFromTime(startTradingTime) >= 0 and SecondsTillTime(endTradingTime) > 0 else yes;
def positionsStillAllowed = if use_trading_hours == yes then SecondsTillTime(noMorePositions) > 0 else yes;

def h = high(period = agg); 
def l = low(period = agg); 
def c = close(period = agg); 
def hh = highest(h, trendPeriods); 
def ll = lowest(l, trendPeriods); 
def trend = if ((c - ll) / (hh - ll)) > .5  
            then 1 
            else 0; 

// Enter long (flip from short if necessary)
addorder(orderType.BUY_AUTO, trend[1] and isTradingSession and positionsStillAllowed and BarNumber()>1, tradesize=1, price=open[-1]+spread); 

// Exit long at EOD
addorder(orderType.SELL_TO_CLOSE, !isTradingSession[-1], tradesize=1, price=open-spread); 

// Enter short (flip from long if necessary)
addorder(orderType.SELL_AUTO, !trend[1] and isTradingSession and positionsStillAllowed and BarNumber()>1, tradesize=1, price=open[-1]-spread); 

// Exit short at EOD
addorder(orderType.BUY_TO_CLOSE, !isTradingSession[-1], tradesize=1, price=open+spread);
```

Due to looking at higher aggregation/timeframe, I use trend[1] to get the previous, fully closed `trend` value to act on the current bar re: repainting.

This is my Pine Script so far that generates no trades in the Strategy Tester, yet shows no syntax or compile errors:

```
// © windowshopr

//@version=5
//=========================== IMPORTS AND STRATEGY ===========================//
strategy("My Strategy", shorttitle="My Strategy", 
     overlay=true, 
     initial_capital=1000, 
     pyramiding=1, 
     calc_on_order_fills=true, 
     calc_on_every_tick=true, 
     backtest_fill_limits_assumption=10, 
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, 
     default_qty_value=100, 
     currency=currency.NONE, 
     slippage=1, 
     commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_contract, 
     commission_value=0.01)



//=========================== INPUTS ===========================//
//========= STRATEGY
input_agg_period = input.timeframe(
     title = "Higher TimeFrame Aggregation Period", 
     defval = "60", 
     group = 'Strategy',
     tooltip = 'The higher timeframe to use with strategy')

input_trend_periods = input.int(
     title = "Trend Periods", 
     minval = 1, 
     defval = 5, 
     group = 'Strategy',
     tooltip = 'The number of bars/periods to use for calculating trend')



//=========================== STRATEGY ===========================//
var float h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, input_agg_period, high)
var float l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, input_agg_period, low)
var float c = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, input_agg_period, close)
var float hh = ta.highest(h, input_trend_periods)
var float ll = ta.lowest(l, input_trend_periods)
var int trend = ((c - ll) / (hh - ll)) > .5 ? 1 : 0

longCondition = trend[1] == 1
shortCondition = trend[1] == 0



//=========================== TIME MANAGEMENT ===========================//
// InSession() returns 'true' when the current bar happens inside
// the specified session, corrected for the given time zone (optional).
// Returns 'false' when the bar doesn't happen in that time period,
// or when the chart's time frame is 1 day or higher. 
InSession(sessionTime, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, sessionTimeZone))
session  = input.session("0730-1400", title="Session")
timeZone = input.string("GMT-6", title="Time Zone")

var bool inRTH = InSession(session, timeZone) 



//=========================== TRADE MANAGEMENT ===========================//
bool openLongPosition = longCondition and inRTH
bool openShortPosition = shortCondition and inRTH

bool closeLongPosition = shortCondition or not inRTH
bool closeShortPosition = longCondition or not inRTH

bool longIsActive = openLongPosition or strategy.position_size > 0 and not closeLongPosition
bool shortIsActive = openShortPosition or strategy.position_size < 0 and not closeShortPosition

// the open signals when not already into a position
bool validOpenLongPosition = openLongPosition and not (strategy.position_size > 0)
bool validOpenShortPosition = openShortPosition and not (strategy.position_size < 0)

// Order Exits
if closeLongPosition and longIsActive
    strategy.close(id = 'Long Entry', comment = 'Close Long', alert_message = 'Long: Closed at market price')
// close on trend reversal
if closeShortPosition and shortIsActive
    strategy.close(id = 'Short Entry', comment = 'Close Short', alert_message = 'Short: Closed at market price')

// Order Entries
if validOpenLongPosition
    strategy.entry(id = 'Long Entry', direction = strategy.long, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')

// getting into SHORT position
if validOpenShortPosition
    strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')
```

Note that if you comment out the RTH/InSession logic from the entry/exit conditions, it opens 1 trade, however I'm trying to get a 1:1 match from ThinkOrSwim, and it trades almost daily over the past few weeks. Can you spot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that you CANNOT use the `var float` declarations if you want to use variable values on a global scope, `var <type>` is meant for local scopes.

The updated code looks like this:

```
//=========================== STRATEGY ===========================//
h = request.security(syminfo.ticker, input_agg_period, high)
l = request.security(syminfo.ticker, input_agg_period, low)
c = request.security(syminfo.ticker, input_agg_period, close)
hh = ta.highest(h, input_trend_periods)
ll = ta.lowest(l, input_trend_periods)
// If "trend" > 0.5, then true/uptrend, else false/downtrend
trendSignal = (c - ll) / (hh - ll) > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
// Update the bar colours for visual inspection
barcolor(trendSignal[1] == 1 ? color.blue : color.red)
// Define some potential entry conditions
longCondition = trendSignal[1] == 1
shortCondition = trendSignal[1] == 0
```